# Wacom Intuos CTL-4100 not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, wacom

I'm pretty much a newcomer in this site and in Ubuntu 18.04. Today I tried using my new Wacom Intuos Small (Model:CTL-4100) in the OS. Just after connecting it to my laptop, it seemed to work just fine. The problem came after noticing that the system did not recognize the pen tablet on the control center. After looking it up, I installed the input-wacom driver following the instructions on its GitHub page. However, after rebooting the system, the pen tablet stopped working at all. It still shows the led light when I connect it by USB, but it does not move the mouse pointer, and the buttons seem to do nothing either. I would like to know if there is a way to go back to the default system drivers for Wacom tablets.
I must add that I also installed libwacom and xf86-input-wacom drivers after the kernel driver, but the tablet still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Sorry - did the tablet start to work under linux properly in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted, on Ubuntu 18.04, the non-Bluetooth Intuos Small is supported at the kernel level without installing the "input-wacom" kernel driver. If you had the Bluetooth version you would need to install an updated input-wacom.

However, updating input-wacom should not cause the tablet to stop working. It is possible that something in your installation of one of the three drivers went wrong.

Nevertheless, to reduce your variables for troubleshooting, you may want to uninstall input-wacom. To return to the default kernel (input-wacom) drivers, you would normally issue the command:

```
 sudo make uninstall
```

in the same directory where you issued the command "sudo make install". A reboot or

```
 modprobe -r wacom; sudo modprobe wacom
```

would be necessary to swap out the currently running driver.

Updating libwacom would be the step required to show the tablet in the Control Panel. An update to xf86-input-wacom would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [official documentation](https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/wiki/Troubleshooting#special-cases), some Wacom Tablets, namely

- Wacom Intuos M: CTL-6100
- Wacom Intuos BT M: CTL-6100WL
- Wacom Intuos S: CTL-4100
- Wacom Intuos BT S: CTL-4100WL

May change their behavior because they missidentify the Linux computer as an Android device, and therefore they won't be picked up by Ubuntu as a Wacom tablet. You can test this by running `libwacom-list-local-devices` on a terminal:

```
$ libwacom-list-local-devices 
# Device node: /dev/input/event8
[Device]
Name=Wacom Intuos S (Android Mode)
...
```

Where you clearly see the tablet is in Android Mode. To change it back, you must press the buttons 1 and 4 (i.e. the rightmost and leftmost) simoultaneously for a number of seconds (around 5). You can run the command again, also while pressing the buttons, and see the output:

```
$ libwacom-list-local-devices 
# Device node: /dev/input/event8
[Device]
Name=Wacom Intuos S
ModelName=CTL-4100
```

Note that now it is properly identified as a Wacom Tablet. After this, Ubuntu should automatically pick it up for configuring.

Answer (score 0):

All we need is the propriety driver that already in the default repository of 18.04. If you have installed libwacom via source, then remove it and just let the repository wacom module take over. See this post for uninstallation - [input-wacom](https://askubuntu.com/a/1044215/791428)!

If  `libwacom-list-local-devices` does not show your device details then you need to add the appropriate .tablet file and .svg file to /usr/share/libwacom. Check this for more details: [libwacom github page](https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/wiki/Troubleshooting)!

Finally, if you see Android mode when you issue the command above, then you need to make it come to nromal mode by pressing first and fourth button simultaneously for around ten seconds. You can simultaneously check the state of `xsetwacom --list devices` when you are still pressing those buttons.
See the Special Cases section in the above github page. This answer may help-[wacom ctl 4100](https://askubuntu.com/a/1236385/791428)