# WACOM Intuos not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, wacom

I can't get a Wacom Intuos to work correctly on Ubuntu 18.04. I got the below outcome. The Stylus cursor always stay on the right edge of the screen. The cursor and pad devices appears to be missing. It was described [here](https://joshuawoehlke.com/wacom-intuos-and-xsetwacom-on-ubuntu-18-04/)

```
$ xsetwacom --list devices
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos S stylus      id: 11  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos S eraser      id: 16  type: ERASER 
$ lsusb | grep Wacom
$ lsusb | grep wacom
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB OPTICAL MOUSE                         id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos S stylus            id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos S eraser            id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_E4HD:            id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
$ lsmod | grep wacom
$
```

The system uses 5.3.0-51-generic #44~18.04.2-Ubuntu x86_64.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. In trying to make it first on my Lenovo Y530 with Ubuntu 18.04 and Wacom Intuos S, I broke my gnome-display manager and keyboard input. I am not sure 100 percent but I think once I installed `xserver-xorg-input-wacom` and updated, it broke the rest of xserver modules. To fix them, I had to uninstall Nvidia graphics settings and `install xserver-xorg-input-all` via root shell in recovery mode.
The following two answers can help you fix those two problems:

1. [Nvidia uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62276101/1100242)!
2. [graphics display and input drivers](https://askubuntu.com/a/1222223/791428)!

If you don't have those problems, then all you need is the propriety driver that already in the default repository of 18.04. If you have installed libwacom via source, then remove it and just let the repository wacom module take over. See this post for uninstallation - [input-wacom](https://askubuntu.com/a/1044215/791428)!

If  `libwacom-list-local-devices` does not show your device details then you need to add the appropriate .tablet file and .svg file to /usr/share/libwacom. Check this for more details: [libwacom github page](https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/wiki/Troubleshooting)!

Finally, if you see Android mode when you issue the command above, then you need to make it come to normal mode by pressing the first and fourth buttons simultaneously for around ten seconds. You can simultaneously check the state of `xsetwacom --list devices` when you are still pressing those buttons.
See the Special Cases section in the above Github page. This answer may help-[wacom ctl 4100](https://askubuntu.com/a/1236385/791428)

I hope it helps you!

Comment: I had trouble with only half of the tablet working. It was in android mode! Changing to normal mode fixed it for me. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, also from my side: For Ubuntu 20.04, I'm just using the driver/kernel module from the Ubuntu repo out of the box. Just changing to normal mode fixed everything, such that `xsetwacom list devices` and `libwacom-list-local-devices` are again listing the `pad` device as expected. Then, I was able to use `xsetwacom ... MapToOutput` to do what I want.

Comment: How to add .tablet and .svg file ? In my case I had Intuos S(ctl 4100). I looked at the libwacom github page and under data folder found that intuos-s-p3-android.tablet is the tablet file for ctl-4100 that is missing from my side. I copied the same to my /usr/share/libwacom, and then also copied the corresponding svg file to the layouts folder and then ran the command libwacom-list-local-devices to see that it's been populated now correctly.