# Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos BT M stopped working corectly

Tags: apt, ppa, wacom

I bought Wacom Tablet and I though that it will work smoothly on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS.. after first plugin the device all works good, but after restart the machine tablet works randomly, like a chaos. What could happen?

I remember that previously the command shown me four items, not only two:

```
twaszczyk@ktwtomwasnb:~$ xsetwacom --list devices
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos BT M stylus   id: 10  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos BT M eraser   id: 16  type: ERASER
```

Does it mean that that the command:

```
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Co.,Ltd. Intuos BT M stylus" PressureCurve 0 20 80 100
```

I need to execute every time on bootstrap the machine? Is it possible to install compiled packages and drivers, while doing it I see that the repository does not work..

```
twaszczyk@ktwtomwasnb:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:doctormo/wacom-plus
 Wacom sometimes needs updated drivers, these drives will sometimes be better than the ones shipped but you should double and triple check. Please test and send error reports to me (see launchpad profile page) https://launchpad.net/~doctormo
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~doctormo/+archive/ubuntu/wacom-plus
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                     
Hit:3 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                   
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88,7 kB]                                            
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                           
Hit:6 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease                                                  
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/doctormo/wacom-plus/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                             
Hit:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                    
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mikhailnov/pulseeffects/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                         
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/doctormo/wacom-plus/ubuntu bionic Release                                              
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Hit:11 https://packagecloud.io/screen/screen/debian buster InRelease                                                   
Reading package lists... Done 
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/doctormo/wacom-plus/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04.5. When I issued `xsetwacom --list devices` un Ubuntu 18.04.4 I always got

```
Wacom Intuos S Pad pad              id: 13  type: PAD       
Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus           id: 15  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos S Pen eraser           id: 16  type: ERASER    
Wacom Intuos S Pen cursor           id: 17  type: CURSOR
```

and everything worked fine. After updating to Ubuntu 18.04.5 and a restart, I only saw two entries after issuing `xsetwacom --list devices`

```
Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus           id: 15  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos S Pen eraser           id: 16  type: ERASER
```

and the tablet/stylos went haywire, i.e., random button presses, only a fourth of the tablet space working, etc.

I found some hints here in this earlier solution: [WACOM Intuos not working on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235513/wacom-intuos-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)

What solved it for me was this tip from the solution above: "...you need to make it come to normal mode by pressing the first and fourth buttons simultaneously for around ten seconds. You can simultaneously check the state of `xsetwacom --list devices` when you are still pressing those buttons."

After I did this and issued `xsetwacom --list devices` I got the familiar four entries back and everything seems to work normal again on Ubuntu 18.04.5

```
Wacom Intuos S Pad pad              id: 13  type: PAD       
Wacom Intuos S Pen stylus           id: 15  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Intuos S Pen eraser           id: 16  type: ERASER    
Wacom Intuos S Pen cursor           id: 17  type: CURSOR
```

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have solved it by installing Ubuntu 20 and works good. Appreciate such well written answer ;-) Have a nice day!