# Wacom Intuos CTL4100 on Ubuntu 18.04: device settings not available

Tags: 18.04, tablet, wacom

I have an Wacom Intuos CTL4100 graphics tablet that I would like to use with my Dell XPS13 running Ubuntu 18.04. After plugging in the tablet, most thing seem to work: the tablet and stylus are recognised, and the cursor reacts to the stylus. However, device settings are not available. See the attached screenshot (screens for tablet and stylus are the same). What can I do to make those settings available?

I have tried the instructions from [this site](https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/wiki/Troubleshooting#special-cases) and hold the left- and right-most buttons for a few seconds, but that did not help. I am hesitant to upgrade wacom drivers, given that the tablet of the author of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043997/wacom-intuos-ctl-4100-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)  stopped working after doing that.

Output from `/usr/bin/libwacom-list-local-devices`:

```
[Device]
Name=Wacom Serial Tablet WACf004
DeviceMatch=serial:0000:0000;
Class=ISDV4
Width=0
Height=0
IntegratedIn=Display;System;
Styli=0xfffff;0xffffe;

[Features]
Reversible=false
Stylus=true
Ring=false
Ring2=false
Touch=false
TouchSwitch=false
StatusLEDs=
NumStrips=0
Buttons=0
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

[image: device settings screenshot]

**==== UPDATE ===**

I've followed the instructions as per SPP's comment below, and copied the `.tablet` file for my tablet to `/usr/share/libwacom`. I now see some settings that i can edit, but fewer than I had hoped. I can only set the tracking mode to absolute or relative (but when the tablet is connected, it can only be set to absolute, relative is not available). Is this what is should be, or should there be more settings? I've included a screenshot for the new situation. Output from `/usr/bin/libwacom-list-local-devices` has not changed.

[image]

Specifically, I would like to be able to be able to scroll with the stylus when pressing the lower button. This is possible on a Mac.

Other annoyances are that I see two mouse pointers, one reacting to the tablet, and one to the touchpad. Sometimes (not that often), the tablet pointer stops reacting at all, and I have to plug the tablet out and back in. All in all, it doesn't feel like everything is well. Could use some advice on what to do.

Comment: It's not clear whether the 2d1f VID problem you mention on the linked page is the problem. Does lsusb show the device as having ID 2d1f:0374 or 056a:0374 ?

Comment: @SPP Sorry for the wait, I thought I had replied already, but apparently I didn't...`lsusb` gives `Bus 001 Device 005: ID 056a:0374 Wacom Co., Ltd `.

Answer (score 1):

you did reply - and I replied to your reply - but a mod converted my original reply to a comment [per here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ca1lk.png) which seemed to lose our subsequent discussion.

(To mods: sorry I'm posting again as an "answer" but I don't seem to have any other option because it says I need 50 reputation to post a comment)

As I said in that post: the lsusb output means the 2d1f VID problem is not the issue. But I suggest putting the .tablet file specific to your tablet into /usr/share/libwacom

I think for your tablet this is:
https://github.com/linuxwacom/libwacom/blob/master/data/intuos-s-p3.tablet

Comment: You could get more reputation by editing other users posts. It will give you 2 point per edit.