# Wacom Issue with the tablet's area

Tags: 20.04, wacom

My issue is that the half of the wacom area moves the cursor around all the screen. English is not my native language so here is visual help:
(I made it with the cursor and fast, don't judge me :D)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wacom Tablets sometimes misidentify the Linux computer as an Android device.
To change that you can follow the steps posted by Aquiles Carattino in

[Wacom Intuos CTL-4100 not working on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1043997/wacom-intuos-ctl-4100-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04/1223106#1223106)